# How many number of ways are there to split an array into k distinct parts?

Tags: split, combinations, combinatorics, arrays

I want to know the number of ways to split an array into k non-null and distinct parts.

For Ex :

```
Array = [1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
```

Then there are 7 ways to split it into 4 different sub-arrays:

```
[[1],[2],[2,2],[2,3,3]]

[[1],[2],[2,2,2],[3,3]]

[[1],[2],[3],[2,2,2,3]]

[[1],[2],[2,3],[2,2,3]]

[[1],[2,2],[3],[2,2,3]]

[[1],[2,3],[2,2,2],[3]]

[[1,2],[2,2],[3],[2,3]]
```

Similarly I want to calculate this for larger array. Is there any way to calculate it ?

**Every element is either 1 or prime number.**

Note : No two sub-arrays are have same value of product of all elements of that sub-array and no sub-array is null.

Comment: are you sure there are 7 ways? I think there is way more than that! consider [1,2,2], ... [1,2,2,2] , ... and ... there is a lot of ways to do that :)

Comment: Ok, I think there's an ambiguity over here. Let me edit it. I think, now its clear, that if you take [1,2],[2],[2,2],[3,3] or something like that, then it will have two sub-arrays [1,2] and [2] with same value of product of its element.

Comment: still there is more than 7 ways, consider [1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3] I could give you lots of other examples!

Comment: Not actually, I have mentioned that I want to split it in k=4 sub-arrays. But your example have only three parts. And every number is either 1 or any prime number as I edited it.

Comment: how could [2,2,2] be a prime number?!

Comment: I'm talking about elements of given array which are 1,2,2,2,2,3,3 and they all are prime. or 1.

Comment: Are you trying to solve Project Euler problem #495?  If so, I don't think this method will be "good enough."

Comment: @TravisJ, Yes. Have you got any other idea ?

Comment: I have other ideas, but haven't tried them yet.  I don't think it is appropriate to ask SO users to solve project euler problems for you... my advice is to solve easier counting problems first and carefully read the forums (learn the math principles) then it will likely be more do-able.

Comment: @TravisJ, of course I do. I thought it would be great to fusion ideas.